# VBA Powerpoint on Mac error when combining presentations with ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile

Tags: vba, macos, file, powerpoint

The goal of my effort is to have a VBA macro that will consolidate a number of PPT presentations into a single PPT presentation. The component presentations that are to be combined are in a number of locations. This seems to be a crucial factor. I found a very good 'almost' solution, but it was based on all of the component presentations being in a single folder. I was able to modify the example, but ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile will only function if the path to a component presentation is hardcoded. I need this to be data-driven. When I try to reference a variable containing the path, ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile fails with the error "Error inserting files Error: -2147483640 Powerpoint could not open the file".

Any assistance to get this running by passing the component path as a variable would be very appreciated. Thanks, Jack

The contents of the MANIFEST.txt file are the two lines:
topic-1/control-structures.pptm
topic-2/cursors.pptm

```
Sub InsertExample()
' Inserts all presentations named in MANIFEST.txt into current presentation in list order
' MANIFEST.txt must be properly formatted, one full path name per line

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim ManifestFileName As String
    Dim ManifestFilePathColons As String
    Dim ManifestFilePathSlashes As String
    Dim iListFileNum As Integer
    Dim ManifestPresentationName As String

    Dim FullPresentationPath As String

    ' name of file containing files to be inserted
    ManifestFileName = "MANIFEST.txt"

    ' use the path with colons to work with the MANIFEST.txt file
    ManifestFilePathColons = "Macintosh HD:Users:freejak:Google Drive:stirling:course-topics:auto-consolidate:"

      ' use the path with slashes to work with the ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile PPT method
    ManifestFilePathSlashes = "Macintosh HD/Users/freejak/Google Drive/stirling/course-topics/auto-consolidate/"

    ' Do we have a file open already?
    ' Debug.Print Presentations.Count
    If Not Presentations.Count > 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    iListFileNum = FreeFile()
    Open ManifestFilePathColons & ManifestFileName For Input As iListFileNum

    ' Process the list
    While Not EOF(iListFileNum)
        ' Get a line from the list file
        Line Input #iListFileNum, ManifestPresentationName

            'The following invocation works, and the seperator must be a slash
        Call ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile("Macintosh HD/Users/freejak/Google Drive/stirling/course-topics/auto-consolidate/topic-1/control-structures.pptm", _
              ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

        FullPresentationPath = ManifestFilePathSlashes & ManifestPresentationName

        'This invocation fails, the same error occurs if I call passing "ManifestFilePathSlashes & ManifestPresentationName" without the quotes
        ' This fails whether the seperators are colons or slashes
        ' Call ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile(FullPresentationPath, ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

    Wend

    Close #iListFileNum
    MsgBox "DONE!"

NormalExit:
    Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant but you’ve got an extra “topic1” subfolder when you type the path out, vs the path written into the string variables.

Comment: egerz, thanks for taking time to review this. Could you please be more specific? In the example where I pass the full path as text there is one reference to "path-1". In the example where I attempt to pass the full path in two variables the first one ends with "auto-consolidate/" and the second one (based on the MANIFEST) contains "topic-1/control-structures.pptm". I don't see an extra "topic1" or "topic-1" subfolder.

Comment: Ah, I see -- can you post the first few lines of the manifest? That's what was throwing me off.

It's possible you're running into a sandbox issue (which can be pretty frustrating with the Mac version), but since InsertFromFile is working with the string typed out, I think it's more likely there's some typo/formatting issue with the string pointing to the presentations.  What's the result when you Debug.Print the FullPresentationPath variable after concatenating?

Comment: Hi egerz, the contents of MANIFEST.txt (only 2lines) are just above the code. Thanks again foryour review.

Comment: Finally had a chance to review this on a Mac, and your code worked for me. Two things:

1. There is a sandboxing issue, as I had to manually grant access to each file. If you cancel the Grant Access bit, you get the "PowerPoint couldn't open the file" error. This is just an annoying part of working with VBA in Mac OS.

2. When I created the manifest file, the first paragraph mark was copied-and-pasted as a line break, so the path didn't import properly. Once I manually added a carriage return, it saw two lines and imported properly (using the variable invocation of InsertFromFile).

Comment: Wow, well it's encouraging that you saw this work. :) I have hunted but cannot find a reference about how to "manually grant access to each file". I tried clicking in the Get Info box of every folder in the path, but that's done no good. I'm familiar with the Unix 'approach' to controlling file permissions with chmod, but can't find anything about the ways and means of using that for the Apple sandbox. Would you please describe the ways and means of getting this all important bit set correctly?

Comment: Correction to above, I tried clicking the "Shared folder" check box in the Get Info dialog of every folder...